Zimbra with multiple domains certificate not working
I have installed & configured Zimbra OSE 8.8.15 on one Server, but I've already configured multiple domains, domain1 & domain2 which is pointing at the Zimbra server, this is working perfectly fine. Now when I’m trying to install a SSL Certificate using Let's Encrypt for the domain1 & domain2 based on this wiki. It's already done, but when I'm trying to check the URL domain1 & domain2, SSL has still using the Self Signed from Zimbra. How to fix this problem??
Here's my nginx.conf.web.https configuration.

We're not clairvoyant. Tell us what your configuration looks like.

which configuration that i should give?

Honestly, Zimbra had grown into "web control panels" which is "customized enough" so that "standard system administration methods no longer apply". For example, there is Postfix in it, but you can't edit main.cf or master.cf, or restart it normal way, or setup certificates for it as you do with normal Postfix system, and so on.
